# Determining the end of a web page

Tags: python, react-native, selenium

I am trying to automate scrolling down a web page written in react native and taking a screenshot of the entire thing.  I've solved that by sending PAGE_DOWN via send_keys.

I am trying to find the end of the page so I know when to stop taking screenshots.  My problem is that the page is dynamic in length depending on the information displayed.  It has collapsible sections that are expanded all at once.  To make it more fun, the dev team decided not to add ids or any unique identifiers because "it's written in react".
I've tried the following:

- Looking for an element at the bottom of the page: the element is 'visible' regardless of where it is on the page.  I've tried different ones with the same result
- Determining the clientHeight, offsetHeight, scrollHeight via javascript: the number it returns doesn't change no matter how many times the page has been moved down, so either I'm not using it right or it won't work.  I'm at a loss right now.

I'm running python with selenium on a Chrome browser (hoping that the solution can be translated to IE).

Comment: Compare the height of the page: When the height of the page doesn't grow, you're done.

Comment: Is the height of the page one of the items I listed above?  If so, none of them change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep taking the Y coordinate of the vertical scrolling bar element each time you performing the scrolling down.
While it keeps changing - you still not reached the page bottom.
Once the page bottom is reached the previous value of vertical scrolling bar will be equal to the current Y coordinate of that element.

Comment: How do I find the vertical scrolling bar?  I thought of that, but couldn't figure out how to locate it.

Comment: To locate the element I obviously need to see the web page

Comment: I was able to use this comment to get a solution.  There was no way I could figure out to find the vertical scrolling bar, so I got the element of something at the bottom of the page.  Then, I did the above.

Comment: Congrats! To find some element on the bottom is the simplest way. I thought there is no such element, that's why I suggested measuring according to the vertical scrolling bar position :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the way I know in Selenium Python bindings :

```
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
```

Comment: How would I use this in my code?  It returns a web element, but I'm kind of lost on how to proceed